# Using both SMPTE and IRIG-B time codes

Tags: timecode

Is there a way to insert both SMPTE and IRIG-B time codes to a video file?

I'm asking because I use video for experimental test purposes and having both allows me to track non-video signal along with the video shot during a test. After it can be used to create visual overlays of data on top of the video clip matched in real time.

Answer (score 1):

If the instrumentation code is available as an audio signal (Modulated or Modified Manchester), it can be added as a new track on the video (separate stream in the file). In a multi-track environment it should survive editing etc.